# Unable to resolve class - Groovy junit testing using maven

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, junit

I am trying to create groovy tests where i use other methods from other Groovy scripts. Whenever i run `mvn test` i get unable to resolve class error, referring to the illegal import from another groovy script.

This is the testclass that I've written :

```
import jenkins_methods.gitMethods
import org.junit.Test

class GitMethodsTest extends GroovyTestCase{


    GitMethodsTest(){

    }

    def gitMethods = new gitMethods()


    @Test
    void testGetDvhBranches(){

        try{
            gitMethods.getDVH_branches()
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            println e
        }
    }
}
```

gitMethods.groovy

```
package jenkins_methods

// src/jobMethods

import dvh.util.AnsiColorDefinition
import jenkins_methods.fileMethods


String getGitDVH_BranchPath_flash() {    return '/git-repository1/git/dvh/branches/' }
String dvhBranchNull() {    return 'feature/DV-null-repo' }

String getDVH_branches() {

            gitURL_DVH= "censored_url"
            String response = sh returnStdout: true, script: "git ls-remote -h ${gitURL_DVH()}"
            def branches = response.replaceAll(/[a-z0-9]*\trefs\/heads\//, ',')
            branches = branches.substring(1, branches.length()).replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "")
            return branches

        }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>jenkins-jobs</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <providerSelection>2.0</providerSelection>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>addSource</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The jenkins_methods package contains various groovy scripts that are necessary for the Tests to become relevant. 
Structure of the project is as following :
 -src 
   -test 
      -groovy 
         -GitMethodsTest.groovy
 -jenkins_methods
   -gitMethods.groovy

This is the error that i get when i run `mvn test`

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:testCompile (default) on project jenkins-jobs: startup failed:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/jenkins-jobs/src/test/groovy/GitMethodsTest.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class jenkins_methods.gitMethods
[ERROR]  @ line 3, column 1.
[ERROR]    import jenkins_methods.gitMethods
[ERROR]    ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] 1 error
```

How do i solve this problem?

Comment: the compiler could not find file with name `.../jenkins_methods/gitMethods.groovy`. what is the structure of the project? what's inside `jenkins_methods` folder?

Comment: Structure of the project is as following :

--src
     --test
           --groovy
                      --GitMethodsTest.groovy

      --jenkins_methods
                 --various groovy methods that is being used to retrieve paths and strings.

Comment: please edit the question and provide all details. and do you have `jenkins_methods/gitMethods.groovy` file?